# NHibernate update all child rows when adding a new child

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm struggling with a problem related to parent-child mapping.
I think I did everything correctly, but every time I add a child and save the parent, nhibernate execute an insert and then an update for all the rows in the child list.
here is my classes and mapping

```
  public class Cliente : EntityBase
  {
    public virtual string Cognome { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual int AttivitaId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DittaAssunzioneData { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Stipendio { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ClienteChiusura> Chiusure { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void AddTelefonata(Telefonata telefonata)
    {
      if (Telefonate == null)
        Telefonate = new List<Telefonata>();
      //NHibernate impedence
      telefonata.Cliente = this;
      Telefonate.Add(telefonata);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveTelefonata(int telefonataId)
    {
      if (Telefonate == null)
        return;
      var telefonata = Telefonate.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == telefonataId);
      if (telefonata != null)
      {
        Telefonate.Remove(telefonata);
        telefonata.Cliente = null;
      }
    }
  }

  public class Telefonata : EntityBase
  {
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descrizione { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Data { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Ingresso { get; set; }
    public virtual string Utente { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UtenteData { get; set; }
    public virtual TelefonataTipo TelefonataTipo { get; set; }
  } 

  public class TelefonataTipo : EntityBase
  {
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
  }


  public abstract class EntityBase
  {
   public virtual int Id { get; private set; }

   //ctor
   protected EntityBase()
   { }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
     return Id.GetHashCode();
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
     return (obj != null && obj.GetType() == GetType() && ((EntityBase)obj).Id == Id);
   }

   public static bool operator ==(EntityBase entity1, EntityBase entity2)
   {
     //cast come object altrimenti ho un loop ricorsivo
     if ((object)entity1 == null && (object)entity2 == null)
       return true;

     if ((object)entity1 == null || (object)entity2 == null)
       return false;

     if (entity1.GetType() != entity2.GetType())
       return false;

     if (entity1.Id != entity2.Id)
       return false;

     return true;
   }

   public static bool operator !=(EntityBase entity1, EntityBase entity2)
   {
     return (!(entity1 == entity2));
   }
}
```

And the mapping is as follow

```
public class ClienteMapping : MappingBase<Evoltel.PuntoQuinto.Domain.Entities.Cliente.Cliente>
  {
    public ClienteMapping()
      : base("CLIENTI")
    {
      Id(x => x.Id, c => { c.Column("CLIENTE_ID"); c.Generator(Generators.Native, g => g.Params(new { sequence = "GEN_CLIENTI_ID" })); });
      Property(x => x.Cognome, c => c.Column("COGNOME"));
      Property(x => x.Nome, c => c.Column("NOME"));
      Property(x => x.AttivitaId, c => c.Column("ATTIVITA_ID"));
      Property(x => x.DittaAssunzioneData, c => c.Column("D_ASSUNZIONE_DATA"));
      Property(x => x.Stipendio, c => c.Column("D_STIPENDIO"));

      Bag(x => x.Telefonate, map =>
      {
        map.Inverse(true);
        map.Table("TELEFONATE");
        map.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        map.Key(k => k.Column("CLIENTE_ID"));
        map.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
      }, r => r.OneToMany());
  }

public class TelefonataMapping : MappingBase<Evoltel.PuntoQuinto.Domain.Entities.Cliente.Telefonata>
{
  public TelefonataMapping()
    : base("TELEFONATE")
  {
    Id(x => x.Id, c => { c.Column("TELEFONATA_ID"); c.Generator(Generators.Native, g => g.Params(new { sequence = "GEN_TELEFONATE_ID" })); });
    ManyToOne(x => x.Cliente, c => c.Column("CLIENTE_ID"));
    Property(x => x.Descrizione, c => c.Column("DESC_LUNGA"));
    Property(x => x.Data, c => c.Column("TELEFONATA_DATA"));
    Property(x => x.Ingresso, c => { c.Column("INGRESSO"); c.Type<TrueFalseType>(); });
    Property(x => x.Utente, c => c.Column("UTENTE_NOME"));
    Property(x => x.UtenteData, c => c.Column("UTENTE_DATA"));
    ManyToOne(x => x.TelefonataTipo, c => { c.Column("TELEFONATA_TIPO_ID"); c.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore); });
  }
}

public abstract class MappingBase<T> : ClassMapping<T> where T : EntityBase
 {
   protected MappingBase(string tableName)
   {
     Table(tableName);
     Lazy(false);
     DynamicUpdate(true);
   }
 }
```

If I do not use Cascade.All the new Child is not saved (and for what I understood of NHibernate it's correct)

What is that I'm not seeing?